# Refresh Indicator not working with NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
     key: _scaffoldKeyProfilePage,

      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
 child:RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, _) {
              return [
                SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                 [                 BuildMainProfile(
              ....//
                 ),
                 Padding(
                ...//another design 
                 ), 
                
              ];
            },
            // You tab view goes here
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'A'),
                Tab(text: 'B'),
              ],
                ),
                Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  BuildPost(,

                  ),
                 BuildWings()
                ],
              ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),),
      ),

  }
```

Refresh Indicator not working with NestedScrollView, is there any way to implement RefreshIndiactor?
I tried adding an empty ListView in Stack, Refresh indicator start showing but because of that my NestedScrollView doesnt scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting `NestedScrollView` widgets `physics` to `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`?

Please see the documentation for [RefreshIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html).

> ***Refresh indicator does not show up***
>
> The RefreshIndicator will appear if its scrollable descendant can be
> overscrolled, i.e. if the scrollable's content is bigger than its
> viewport. To ensure that the RefreshIndicator will always appear, even
> if the scrollable's content fits within its viewport, set the
> scrollable's Scrollable.physics property to
> **AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics**:
>
> ```
> ListView(   
> physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),  
> children: ... )
> ```
>
> A RefreshIndicator can only be used with a vertical scroll view.

Comment: It's partially working. Thing is I am having a bottom navigation bar even, So without it, It works, but with it, It does not work

Comment: A bit confusing, could you please use name of what working and what isn't instead of saying it is working and it is not.

Comment: If I am not having the bottom navigation bar, I am able to see the refresh indicator, but with bottom, navigation bar it's again not showing the refresh Indicator.

Comment: Some minimum reproducible code would be required. Your above code does not even have Bottom Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to wrap '**body**' of the `NestedScrollView` with `RefreshIndicator` widget if the headers won't change when refreshed but only the content change happens for '**body**'.